# Deleting all QueryTables in Excel 2007 Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, interop

Using Excel Interop, I'm attempting to loop through all QueryTables in all Worksheets and delete them.  I've got this code, which works:

```
> // loop through each Worksheet
> for (int i = 1; i <= workbook.Sheets.Count; i++)
> {
>     sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(i);
> 
>     // loop through each queryTable on each Worksheet
>     int queryTableCount = sheet.QueryTables.Count;
>     for (int j = 1; j <= queryTableCount; j++) {
>        sheet.QueryTables.Item(1).Delete();
>     }
> }
```

This works just fine for some data connections/files, but for others the "QueryTables.Count" returns zero - even though I know that there *are* connections.  The connections were created in Excel 2007 via the Data tab-->From Other Sources-->From Microsoft Query. Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, thanks to [this post.](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=89168&page=1)  It turns out that Excel Interop handles query tables differently in the 2003 vs. 2007 versions of Excel.  2007 uses *ListObjects*, so use the same code to loop through each Worksheet like above, but then use:

```
// loop through each list object on each Worksheet
if (sheet.ListObjects.Count > 0)
{
   foreach (ListObject obj in sheet.ListObjects)
   {
     obj.QueryTable.Delete();
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems to handle them differently in VBA as well. Enumerating Listobjects worked there as well.