# Removing queries from Excel workbook usng C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have a C# application that edits Excel Workbooks. One of the processes involves removing Excel query connections from a workbook.

```
 foreach (WorkbookConnection conn in ExcelWorkbook.Connections)
                             conn.Delete();
```

The above code removes the connections, but the query definitions remain in the workbook. Is there a way to disconnect the Table from the query completely (while keeping the actual table in the workbook)?

This VBA code does exactly what I'm trying to do:

```
Workbook.Queries(i).Delete
```

But I can't seem to find anything equivalent using C# Interop.

*EDIT:

Here's my latest code (adapted from Mikev's code in the answer below - still not working):

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Workbook ExcelWorkbook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"MyWorkbook.xlsx");
        ExcelApp.Visible = true;

        for (int i = 1; i <= ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.Count; i++)
        {
            Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)ExcelWorkbook.Sheets.get_Item(i);
            if (sheet.ListObjects.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ListObject obj in sheet.ListObjects)
                {
                    obj.QueryTable.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you just need to copy the table and pastespecial value.  There is a hidden query in the worksheet.  I usually select the entire worksheet and do a copy and pastespecial.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= workbook.Sheets.Count; i++)
{
    sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(i);   
    if (sheet.ListObjects.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (ListObject obj in sheet.ListObjects)
       {
          obj.QueryTable.Delete();
       }
    }
}
```

Credits: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425962/deleting-all-querytables-in-excel-2007-workbook)!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work - query is still in the workbook.

Comment: I never noticed that creating a Query automatically creates a Table (ListObject).  This should be the accepted answer.  It will retain the existing data as well as removing the query. Also, make sure that this is done before removing the connection to assure that the data is current.

Comment: Are u looping through the sheets before this code? I'll edit the code right now

Comment: I did try running it through the loop - the query is still there.

Comment: Mikev, I added it to the question. Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Queries are in the Workbook object

```
foreach (var q in ExcelWorkbook.Queries)
    q.Delete();
```

Comment: Hi, @Fabulous can you expand your questions so it's more clear what it's doing and how it corresponds to the questions asked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the query and connction separately as follows:

```
            Connections allConn = excelWorkbook.Connections;
            Queries queries = excelWorkbook.Queries;

            int i = 0;
            foreach (WorkbookQuery query in queries)
            {
                i++;
                if (query.Name == "<Your Query Name>")
                {
                    query.Delete();
                }
            }
            i = 0;
            foreach (WorkbookConnection conn in excelWorkbook.Connections)
            {
                if(conn._Default == "<Your Connection Name>")
                {
                    conn.Delete();
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Note: the query and connection names need to be specified as the workbook may contain internal queries and connections if it is using Pivots and References which cannot be deleted